# What causes self-charging of foil capacitors?

Tags: capacitor, safety

High-voltage foil capacitors are shipped with shorting brackets to prevent the buildup of dangerous charge. But once in a circuit that is not energized, such a safety shunt will be an awkward complication, because NC switches for several kV are rather exotic.

In the circuit, I could tolerate a self-charging up until about 3 kV without any adverse effect. The passive shunt resistance is on the order of 100 MΩ, so there would be 30 µA of discharge happening at 3 kV.

I am wondering:

- What is the mechanism for the self-charging?
- How much effective charging current could  I expect worst case (say the capacitor terminals just end in the air with no additional precautions)?
- Is the passive shunt resistance sufficient to prevent a dangerous self charging.

Comment: I think the capacitor is not "self-charging", but "not completely discharging" instead. For your circuit, the shunt is more likely *not* "against self-charging", but *for* "discharging": Imaging you once charged it, and put it aside (without having a discharging resistor). After two days someone touches the capacitor...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Once in a circuit, you do not need safety shorts across capacitors.

For shipping, there are two good reasons they come with shorts

- They can get charged from friction with packaging or handling machinery
- Consider the receiving unpacker. You don't know the capacitor's history, and if there's no short on it, it may be charged, or may not be. If you can see a physical short across the terminals, you know it is uncharged.

Comment: Even though all answers provide valuable points of view, I think this one cuts down to the essence that in-circuit leakage (at least in my case) is sufficient to prevent charge build up. The dielectric desorption current should decay over time if there is no additional triboelectric charging.

Comment: And they are charged to high test voltage in the factory during the QA process - adding the short makes it easier for them to verify that the cap has really been discharged.

Answer (score 4):

If used in unipolar fashion for some time and then discharged to zero again, they may “remember” the polarity and pick up some voltage by themselves if left unconnected for weeks (high pA to low uA of current equivalent). Best guess across me and my colleagues when we observed it was some polarization effect on the dielectric. May be strongly dependent on what dielectric is used, metallization and so on.

Comment: Is this dielectric absorption or soakage you are referring to? Wikipedia lists some values of around 1% or less of the max. voltage depending on dielectric. Would you agree to these figures or can it be also much more?

Comment: @We got about 7 % of the previously applied DC voltage if I recall correctly. Zapped my colleague.

Comment: What dielectric type?

Comment: degraded electrolytics sometimes go way above 1%

Comment: @fraxinus The question is about foil caps though.

Answer (score 4):

I think winny is likely right regarding the capacitor "remembering" the voltage applied and I'd like to elaborate a little on the mechanism.

Usually we can assume the [polarization density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_density) is proportional to the E-field in most dielectrics, i.e. \$\mathbf P = \epsilon_0\chi\mathbf E\$, where \$\chi\$ is the [electric susceptibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_susceptibility). However, it may happen that after a high voltage is applied for a long time, there is an additional residual polarization \$\mathbf P_0\$ in the direction of the E-field that remains for a long time even after the  capacitor field is removed. This is seen in [ferroelectric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferroelectricity) materials, and has also been observed in polymers (see e.g. [N.-J. Yang et al.](https://doi.org/10.1002/adfm.200902129)) and attributed to the segmental motion of the large polymer molecules that occurs during the application of E-field, which then take a long time to randomize after the field has been removed ([X. Yuan et al.](https://doi.org/10.1021/ma100209d)). It could also be caused by the [piezoelectric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezoelectricity) if the capacitor temperature is elevated during operation for example, but that's speculation on my part, and is unlikely if the capacitor voltage develops over the course of days or longer rather than in minutes.

The charge on plates of the shorted capacitor with remnant polarization is proportional to the D-field in the dielectric:
$$\mathbf D=\mathbf P_0.$$
This means there is charge on the plates even though the capacitor is shorted. After a long time (days/weeks), the remnant polarization decays to zero (or at least a smaller value). However, the D-field remains constant as long as the capacitor isn't leaky. It must then be provided by an E-field, i.e.
$$\mathbf D = \mathbf P_0 = \epsilon\mathbf E$$
$$\mathbf E = \mathbf P_0/\epsilon.$$
A non-zero E-field means a voltage has developed across the capacitor terminals. Note that the charge on the plates is still the same as before. Apparently there is a name for this phenomenon: [dielectric absoption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_absorption).